How to change only the node value of a pie chart in javafx
I have a pie chart showing the number of students per department in a school. I want only the node values to show both the department id and the number of students in the department.
I found a workaround that extends the Pie Chart class but that is not what I want. Is it possible?
I only want the values to append to the chart nodes. It is a workaround because it adds the values to both the chart nodes and the chart legend and then hides the chart legend.
The first image is normally how a pie chart would look like.

The second image, I used the bind method to add the values using pieValueProperty but it added the value to the chart nodes and the chart legend below.

Here is my sample method that gets the data from a database. It is part of a controller class that handles the dashboard.
private void departmentPieChart() {
    
    ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ResultSet resultSet = Model.getInstance().getConnectDB().getPieChartData();
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            pieChartData.add(new PieChart.Data(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getInt(2)));

        }

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(connectDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    dashboard_pieChartDepartments.setData(pieChartData);
}

I tried binding the pieValueProperty with nameProperty but it changed the node and the label. I don't know if I am missing something.

Can you clarify this question? In your images, what is the observed behavior and what is the desired behavior? What is the workaround you found? In what sense is it a workaround (and not a solution), and (importantly) why is it not what you want?

The first image is normally how a pie chart would look like. The second image, I used the bind method to add the values using pieValueProperty but it added the value to the chart nodes and the chart legend below. I only want the values to append to the chart nodes.
It is a workaround because it adds the values to both the chart nodes and the chart legend and then hides the chart legend.

If the legend isn't displaying what you want you can create your node for the legend and format and populate it how you want.  setLegend allows you to apply your customized legend.  You probably need to design and create the legend from scratch if you do that because the default legend classes are internal to JavaFX and not exposed, but doing so will allow you complete flexibility and control over the legend content.

The code for the basic legend class is here.  Unlike a lot of the standard JavaFX control implementations, the Legend class is pretty short and simple.  Just copy it to create a new class with a different name in your own code base and package, for example PieLegend -> then customize it as you see fit.  If you supplied a [mcve] in your question, I'd add an answer with a solution, but without one, you make more work for somebody to do that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe you can get some ideas from @jewelsea's answer here.  I would guess you can have the node always display instead of only displaying on hover. Just a guess.
